# Take a Picture of Persenels with a Digital Camera Attached To Computer

Tags: c#, winforms, camera

I Want Create a Win-Form Application Can be Connect to a Digital Camera Attached to My Computer.I Want See a LiveView of Persenels in Computer And Then Take a Picture of Persenels.

How Can I Implement This Action?

What Camera Can I Use?

What Component Or Library Can I Use??

What SDk Tools Can I Use??

Please Help me...

Comment: What digital camera? Does it have any TWAIN drivers or similar? Some cameras are controllable over the wire, others are not.

Comment: Are you talking about a WebCam, or a Compact Camera? If it's a compact camera depending on the manufacturer you've to use a DLL or another. I think that Canon has a nice DLL for duing it.

Comment: Albin Sunnanbo@ What Model Of Camera Can I Use For Control Over the Wire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the Windows Image Acquisition API.  Get this started with Project + Add Reference, Browse tab, navigate to c:\windows\system32\wiaaut.dll.  That's a COM component, you'll get an interop library for it with interface types in the WIA namespace.

First thing you want to do is get a reference to the camera, use WIA.ShowSelectDevice().  It returns a Device object if there's only one camera attached, a dialog to let the user select if there are more.  Like this:

```
    public static WIA.Device SelectCamera() {
        var dlg = new WIA.CommonDialog();
        try {
            return dlg.ShowSelectDevice(WIA.WiaDeviceType.CameraDeviceType, false, false);
        }
        catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex) {
            if (ex.ErrorCode == -2145320939) return null;
            throw;
        }
    }
```

That ought to get you started.  Check out the code snippets at this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms630826%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for more of the thing you can do with the API.  Beware that not all cameras allow you do use them interactively when they are attached to the machine.  My cheapo point-and-shoot doesn't.

Comment: What the camera to perform this operation you suggest?